# Realizar soma de horas a partir de uma query

Tags: javascript, mysql

estou precisando de uma ajuda em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo, ele é baseado em um sistema de ponto eletrônico eu estou quase finalizando ele, e para concluir de vez preciso realizar um cálculo de horas trabalhadas de um determinado período (ano/mês). A query eu já tenho funcional, a unica coisa que está restando realmente é pegar os registros desta query e somar todos para dai gerar as horas trabalhadas daquele período em especifico, estarei mostrando a query abaixo.

```
SELECT r.cod,r.cod_usuario, r.data, r.entrada, r.intervalo, r.retorno, r.saida, j1.descricao AS justificativa_entrada, j2.descricao AS justificativa_saida,
                        j3.descricao AS justificativa_intervalo, j4.descricao AS justificativa_retorno FROM registro AS r
                        LEFT JOIN justificativa AS j1 ON r.justificativa_entrada = j1.cod
                        LEFT JOIN justificativa AS j2 ON r.justificativa_saida = j2.cod
                        LEFT JOIN justificativa AS j3 ON r.justificativa_intervalo = j3.cod
                        LEFT JOIN justificativa AS j4 ON r.justificativa_retorno = j4.cod
                        WHERE r.cod_usuario = ?  ${monthQuery ? ('AND' + monthQuery) : ''} ${yearQuery ? ('AND' + yearQuery) : ''}           
                        ORDER BY r.data DESC LIMIT 120
```

Essa é a query, e o retorno dela fica dessa forma:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho também já um código que realiza o cálculo das horas trabalhadas porém essa é individualmente, ou seja, é o calculo de cada linha dos registro. (**Date.timeSumFi** é somente um teste)

```
var horasTrabFiltro = Date.timeSumFi((Date.calcHrTrab(re.entrada, re.intervalo, re.retorno, re.saida)));

   Date.calcHrTrab = function (date1, date2, date3, date4) {
        if (date1 == null && date2 == null && date3 == null && date4 == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (date1 != null && date2 != null && date3 != null && date4 != null) {
            dataTrab = Date.timeSum(Date.timeDifference(date1, date2), Date.timeDifference(date3, date4));
            return dataTrab;
        } else if (date1 != null && date2 == null && date3 == null && date4 != null) {
            let date1_ms = new Date(date1).getTime();
            let date4_ms = new Date(date4).getTime();
            let difference_ms = date4_ms - date1_ms;
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 1000;
            let seconds = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 60;
            let minutes = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 60;
            let hours = Math.floor(difference_ms);
            return new Date(0, 0, 0, hours, minutes, seconds, 0);
        } else if (date1 != null && date2 != null) {
            let date1_ms = new Date(date1).getTime();
            let date2_ms = new Date(date2).getTime();
            let difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 1000;
            let seconds = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 60;
            let minutes = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 60;
            let hours = Math.floor(difference_ms);
            return new Date(0, 0, 0, hours, minutes, seconds, 0);
        }
    }
```

Desculpe tanta informação mas acredito que quanto mais explicado melhor para que vocês possam me ajudar no meu problema, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Quando preciso manipular datas com javascript, eu costumo usar uma lib muito boa chamada  ```moment```, caso ainda não conheça aconselho dar uma olhada na documentação tem bastante conteúdo e acho que vai te ajudar bastante nas manipulações de datas. [doc-moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um jeito simples de resolver sem biblioteca nenhuma. Bom como você já tem a função para calcular as horas trabalhadas individualmente é  fazer um loop no seu array vindo do banco passando cada data individualmente armazenando os valores em um outro array, e ao final soma o array de resultados de horas trabalhadas.

```js
var horasTrabalhadasDia = [];

//Suponha que resp é seu array vindo da query
resp.forEach(function(re){
    //Suponha que sua função calcHrTrab retorne já o valor das horas trabalhadas
    horasTrabalhadasDia.push(Date.calcHrTrab(re.entrada, re.intervalo, re.retorno, re.saida)); 
});

//Soma de todas as horas trabalhadas durante o mês
var totalHorasMes = horasTrabalhadasDia.reduce((a, p) => a + p);
```

Bom é um exemplo simples mais que o resultado será a soma de todas as horas trabalhadas de um determinado período.

Comment: Então me recomendaram usar reduce mas fiquei de ver a doc. dele poderia me explicar o que é feito ali em "reduce((a + p) => a + p); "?

Comment: Então ```reduce``` realiza uma agregação dos valores de um array, onde você pode especificar qual tipo de operação deve ser realizada. ```reduce``` recebe como parâmetro uma função com dois paramentos de entrada que representa o primeiro valor do array e o seu sucessor, então você especifica o que deve ser feito com esses valores (no caso acima foi somar os dois), quando isso é feito, ele armazena o valor do resultado no primeiro parâmetro(no caso acima a variável de entrada a), e continua a execução  até terminar todos os elementos do array, gerando no final um acumulado dos valores do array.

Comment: Então no meu caso eu preciso mudar esses parâmetros? Porque está com erro na parte dos parametros nisso "=>" e no final ");"

Comment: Realmente tem uma falha no recebimento dos paramentros vou corrigir

Comment: Tinha colocado o sinal de **+** no recebimento dos parametros era uma **,**

Comment: Na verdade esse código seria o loop for, porém utilizando a estrutura foreach, para percorrer o array, a forma que você vai percorrer o array até não importa tanto, o essencial é calcular os valor de horas de todos os registros e armazenar em um outro array, para poder fazer o reduce. 
Você poderia pegar esta parte e passar no seu loop for ```horasTrabalhadasDia.push(Date.calcHrTrab(re.entrada, re.intervalo, re.retorno, re.saida)); ```. criando a varival ```horasTrabalhadasDia```  fora do loop